# How can I fix my favicon link to make it work

Tags: html, css

[Faulty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA2yo.png)

I am confused why my  (line 4) is not working. I want to add favicon to my site.
I don't think my address is wrong(you can check by seeing the document list on the left on picture attached) What's the problem? Please help me.

Comment: Add your Code please.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<link rel="icon" href="css-my-style/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: remove this shortcut from rel attribute

Answer (score 0):

I believe you run into problems because your syntax is incorrect, try Instead of line 4:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css-my-style/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the type of the icon (type="image/x-icon") in the tag.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="css-my-site/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: still not working. do you know if I need to install anything like modules or packages in order to have this link function working. Because not only this doesn't work but for stylesheet it is not working neither. I am doubting if my link function is broken.

Comment: Which plat form are you using for http server? Is it Apache, IIS or Tomcat ...? You set the correct permission to access the files on target folder. This works for me in a pure HTML file saved on the desktop. <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/Mylogo.png" type="image/x-icon">